# Return json object(s) in list by key: value in Python

Tags: python, json

I have this list of json objects, and I'd like to create a method that returns all commit (or project) entries where `project_id : 1`, for example.  Is this possible?

I currently have `all_commits = all_data[0]['commits']` , which represents all of the commit objects, and a method `def findAll(self):return all_commits` which returns all of them, but I cant figure out how to return *some* of the records.  I can return the *value* of a record via:

```
  def findOne(self, index, key):
    return all_commits[index][key]
```

But how can I return the whole object?

---

```
     [
            {
                "commits": [
                    {
                        "project_id": "1",
                        "commit_title": "commit 1",
                        "date": "date 1",
                        "markdown": "markdown 1"
                    },
                    {
                        "project_id": "1",
                        "commit_title": "commit 2",
                        "date": "date 2",
                        "markdown": "markdown 2"
                    },
                    {
                        "project_id": "1",
                        "commit_title": "commit 3",
                        "date": "date 3",
                        "markdown": "markdown 3"
                    },
                    {
                        "project_id": "1",
                        "commit_title": "commit 4",
                        "date": "date 4",
                        "markdown": "markdown 4"
                    },
                    {
                        "project_id": "2",
                        "commit_title": "commit 5",
                        "date": "date 5",
                        "markdown": "markdown 5"
                    },
                    {
                        "project_id": "2",
                        "commit_title": "commit 6",
                        "date": "date 6",
                        "markdown": "markdown 6"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "projects": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "project_name": "GreenGlass for Groups",
                        "description": "Support group projects for retention agreements"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "project_name": "Zumo Redesign",
                        "description": "New eda theme-based design"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
```

Comment: import json and var jsonString =  json.dumps(all_commits)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter with a list comprehension (or a genex when you get there).

```
[commit for commit in all_commits if commit['project_id'] == '1']
```

Comment: `y = [commit for commit in all_commits if commit['project_id'] == 1]
return y` returns `[ ]`

Comment: @redress: For some reason your data has IDs as strings. Try the updated code.